# Compate DateTime.Ticks on different machines ms resolution

Tags: .net, datetime, time, client-server, network-protocols

I have an application network topology client server in a star formation.  I'm trying to count the millisecond for a message sent from 1 client to the rest.

All  computer synchronize to windows time server.  This I presume is the problem - that maybe they are all accurate +/- X milliseconds and its messing me up.

Anyways I send a message and inside the message I store the .NET DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks

In each client I compare the local machine DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks to the value stored in the packet.  I get the ms here by dividing the difference by 10,000.  I will usually be 70ms or 100ms depending on what client computer I use.  Occasionally I will get something ridiculous like -300ms.  This means the receiving client computer time is more than 350ms earlier than that of the sender.

Is the problem the time synchronization?   Is there a way to get the information I want easily?

I need the client to know in real time how stale is the information to the resolution of a hundred milliseconds.  The only way I can imagine is to send test packets to measure a standard, take the average and have my clients determine relative staleness (since they will deal with stuff like -350ms )

Thank you,

Comment: Why don't you use ICMP(ping). When you get the response, you have the time  for ping+pong and insensitive to machine times.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristian%27s_algorithm